# PHPMailer HTML cannot be read by other mail box

Tags: php, html, css, email

I'm trying to send some html mail with PHPMailer on Phalcon.
I arrive to send them but when I open a mail on my mail box (outlook or gmail) it didn't take in account the css associate to html mail. But when I open it on Thunderbird it take in account the css. So I don't understand why mail boxes can't read css style.

Here the mail :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
  <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   <title id="titre">Mail Gagnant</title>
   <style id="style">
    body{
      background-color:#d41d1d;
      overflow:hidden;
      background-image:url(/jeux/346/mailgagnants_background_mail);
    }
    #header{
      max-width:100%;
      height:auto;
    }
    #footer{
      max-width:100 %; 
      height:auto;
    }
   </style>
  </head>
  <body>
   <img id="header" src="/jeux/346/mail/gagnants_header_mail" alt="header">
     <div id="body"> 
       <div id="content">
         <b>Bonjour&nbsp;&nbsp; </b>
         <font face="Times New Roman">je suis un test</font>
         <br>
       </div>
     </div>
     <img id="footer" src="/jeux/346/mail/gagnants_footer_mail" alt="footer">  
    </body>
 </html>
```

Generate by this code :

```
$this->mail->From  = "------@-------.---";
$this->mail->FromName   =  "----";
$this->mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$this->mail->addAddress($dest);
$this->mail->Subject = $mail->objet;
$this->mail->Body=file_get_contents($jeu->directory."mail/$type_mail.phtml");
$this->mail->AltBody='La boite mail n est pas compatible avec les mails HTML'; 
$this->mail->IsHTML(true);       
$this->mail->send();
```

And PHPMailer parameters are like that :

```
'mail' => array(
'smtp' => array(
    'server' => 'my server',
    'port' =>myport ,
    'security' => 'tls',
    'username'=> 'username',
    'password' => 'pwd'
    )
)
```

Comment: Your HTML is not valid. You can not put IDs on title and style tags. Putting your CSS styles in head section is not a good practice, you should prefer inline your CSS. And the URLs to your images have to be absolute.

Comment: lddz is right, you need to put your CSS inline instead of in a <style> block, your email client is probably stripping out the classes and ids.